# POST http://localhost:3000/users/register 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Hi everyone here I try to send post request API to the server using redux and react that including information about the user of the app, so it renders me this kind of error "POST http://localhost:3000/users/register 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)" please can someone help me to fix this error. any help is appreciated. this is my code :

```
enter code here
```

```
userAction.js:

import { actionTypes } from "../constants/action-types";
import Axios from "axios";

const register = (name, fname, email, phone, password)=> async(dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: actionTypes.REGISTER_USER_REQUEST, payload: {name, fname, email, phone, password}});
    try {
        const {data} = await Axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/users/register",{name,fname,email,phone,password})
        dispatch({type: actionTypes.REGISTER_USER_SUCCESS, payload: data})
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({type: actionTypes.REGISTER_USER_FAIL, payload: error.response && error.response.message.data ? error.response.message.data : error.response})
    }
}
export default register;
```

```
enter code here
```

```
userReducer.js:
import {actionTypes} from "../constants/action-types";

const initialState = {loading: true, userInfos: {}};

export const userReducer = (state= initialState, {type, payload}) => {
switch (type) {
    case actionTypes.REGISTER_USER_REQUEST:
        return {loading: true};
        case actionTypes.REGISTER_USER_SUCCESS:
            return {loading: false, userInfos: payload};
            case actionTypes.REGISTER_USER_FAIL:
                return {loading: false, error: payload}
            default: 
            return state
}
}
```

```
enter code here
```

```
store.js:
import { combineReducers, compose, applyMiddleware, createStore } from "redux";
import { userReducer } from "./reducers/userReducer";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

const reducers = combineReducers({
   user: userReducer
});
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const store = createStore(reducers, {user: {}},
 composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))
    );

export default store;
```

```
enter code here
```

```
registerPage.js:
import React from "react";
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";
import InputGroup from "./common/InputGroup";
import {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import  register from "../redux/actions/userAction";
import {useNavigate, useParams} from "react-router-dom";

const RegisterPage = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
   
   const [name, setName] = useState('');
   //const [user, setUser] = useState({});
   const [fname, setFname] = useState('');
   const [phone, setPhone] = useState('');
   const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
   const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
   const [confirm, setConfirm] = useState('');
  
   //const navigate = useNavigate();
   const validateEmail = (email) => {
    return String(email)
      .toLowerCase()
      .match(
        /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
      );
  };


const {userInfos} = useSelector(state=> state.user);
console.log(userInfos)
  const submitHandler = (event) => {
  
    if(password === confirm && validateEmail(email)) { 
     
      dispatch(register(name, fname, email, phone, password))
    } else {
        window.alert("password and confirm password not the same try again or email not conform!")
      }
    

      };
      useEffect((event)=> {
        submitHandler()
      }, [])

      return (
        <div>
        <h2>Welcome to private <span>Let's be private</span></h2>
       
        <p id="icon" >Pr</p>
        <div className="form">
            <InputGroup value={name} type="text" label="name" name="name" onChange={(e)=> setName(e.target.value)}  />
            <InputGroup value={fname} type="text" label="fname" name="fname" onChange={(e)=> setFname(e.target.value)}/>
            <InputGroup value={phone} type="phone" label="phone" name="phone" onChange={(e)=> setPhone(e.target.value)}/>
            <InputGroup value={email} type="email" label="email" name="email" onChange={(e)=> setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
            <InputGroup value={password} type="password" label="password" name="password"  onChange={(e)=> setPassword(e.target.value)} />
            <InputGroup value={confirm} type="password" label="confirm password" name="confirm"  onChange={(e)=> setConfirm(e.target.value)} />
            <button onClick={(e)=> submitHandler(e)} >Register</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    )  
   
   
  }

export default RegisterPage;
```